# How to sort data using a custom list which contains numbers using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a *Custom List* made which contains **Numbers** only and when I try to sort the Data's using the *Custom List*, it simply **sorts** the Data's in Ascending/Descending order and does not sort based on the arrangement of *Custom List*.
How do we **sort** the data using a *Custom List* containing **Numbers** only.

The idea that i came up with is to add a string to the *Custom List* data as well as data that need to be **sorted** and then sort it.
Is it possible to sort data's without changing/adding anything in worksheet ?

[image: Picture Reference]

Comment: Seeing sample data and the expected outcome would be useful here

Comment: Link to the sample file is attched :  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OgvYM4EeXqN4rvoyvcjumFlmh81iVw_H/view?usp=sharing     ... Try using both **Numeric** and **String** column data ! Replace the Blue colored cells on both sheets with **Numeric** and **String** column data !

Comment: After that run the macro and you'll see that **Numeric** data will sort on ascending order irrespective to **Custom list** where as  **String** data will sort based on **Custom list**.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if the rows.count is syntax right, but something along the lines of:

'Sort range "rng1" (eg. A4:X100) by descending Range A'

```
rng1.Sort key1:=Range("A4:A" & Rows.Count), Order1:=xlDescending
```

'or other option Order1:=xlAscending'